# GDK - Launch back into the app from live-card

Tags: android-intent, android-service, google-gdk

I want to relaunch back into the app after the user is done with the Live-Card. So I have a menu-item in the live card action that intent back into the app. However I encountered a really weird issue. After the user is back into the app and from the app they relaunch the new live-card, the live card action(Pending Intent) is changed for some reason. It launched one of the parent activity and if I swipe out the activity (close the activities), I will see my live card which I should, because though closing those activities does not call unpublished(). And now from there, the live card action (Pending intent) is showing correctly !? Anyone know what is going on? I am so confuse.

So This is how I published my live-card from a service (SomeService.java)

```
    if (mLiveCard == null) {
        TimelineManager timelineManager = TimelineManager.from(this);
        mLiveCard = timelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_TAG);

        // Keep track of the callback to remove it before unpublishing.
        mDrawer = new Drawer(this);
        mLiveCard.setDirectRenderingEnabled(true).getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(mDrawer);

        Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, DrawerMenuActivity.class);
        mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, menuIntent, 0));

        mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);
    } else {
        // TODO(alainv): Jump to the LiveCard when API is available.
    }
```

And this is how I try to launch it back into the app (DrawerMenuActivity.java)

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection.
        Intent intent;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem_return_to_app:
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            mCurrSelectedAction = RecordMenuAction.RETURN;
            bindService(new Intent(this, SomeService.class), sendActionConnection, 0);
            stopService(new Intent(this, SomeService.class));
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. The way that I destroy (remove callback and unpublish the live card) my live card was wrong. This is the correct way of doing it.

```
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mLiveCard != null) {
        mLiveCard.unpublish();
        mLiveCard.getSurfaceHolder().removeCallback(mDrawer);
        mLiveCard = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```